# Android keep BroadcastReceiver running in background

Tags: android, background, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I did a service starts a BroadcastReceiver. The BroadcastReceiver is working only if the app is shown i recent apps screen. When I remove the app from recent apps screen the BroadcastReceiver stops.
How can I save the BroadcastReceiver always in background?

Answer (score 1):

Your service might get killed along with your activity
You should add `process=":background"` in your manifest file within the `<service />` node.

Or, alternatively,
In your service, you must return `START_STICKY`

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>declare the BroadcastReceiver in its own class, and add it to the Android Manifest, instead of registering it with some context.</s>

[This should be a simple starting point for you](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#startingservices_alarmmanager)

Whoops I'm wrong. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED

Comment: I use ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED. I can't declate it from the manifest.

Comment: set an `intent filter` for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` in the manifest, and double check it in the broadcast onReceive() method with `if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)) { // do stuff }`

Comment: oops, I am dead wrong http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED